# What airlines offer free meals/alcohol from Europe to the States?

Tags: air-travel, ireland

I live in Ireland and I'm planning on travelling to New York/Los Angeles during Christmas. I'd like to enjoy complimentary alcohol/food on my long flight. Which airlines would offer free food and drinks?

Comment: Getting the cheapest/most convenient flight and buying food/alcohol on board will often work out better overall, I think.

Comment: @ajd the OP didn't say they're looking for a cheap flight, the OP said they're looking for complimentary food and drink.

Comment: @littleadv is the food and drink really complimentary if the additional cost of buying a flight that offers it is more then what you would pay for the food and drink?

Comment: Most transatlantic flights serve free meals. Few serve free alcohol (except higher classes).

Comment: @DJClayworth Few? From personal experience, United and AA do. With a cursory search I can't find any transatlantic flights that don't offer free alcoholic drinks in economy (at least with 'full service' airlines, not discount ones like Norwegian).

Comment: Oops, on reflection I think you are right. I thought of "complimentary alcohol" as serving as much alcohol of any type as the passenger wants, rather than the "would you like some wine with your meal" which I agree is ubiquitous.